# Firebase - how to get an object from a list of objects by key

Tags: javascript, firebase

Firebase - how to get an object from list of objects by key.

**This is my current example:**

```
 var query = this.refJob.orderByChild("key").equalTo(key); 
 query.on('value', (snap) => console.log(snap.val()));
```

Returns null though.

I'm trying to get 1 object from firebase table.
Its not a child field im trying to get.

I have the key and want to get the object by key.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Selecting by key doesn't require a query, it requires constructing a path to the data.**

```
var ref = new Firebase('<my-firebase-app>');
var key = "someKey";
var keyRef = ref.child(key);
keyRef.on('value', (snap) => console.log(snap.val());
```

Firebase is a key-value store, every piece of data has a URL mapped to it as a key.

Take the following data:

```
{
  "someKey": {
    "title": "I'm a key"
  }
}
```

The `someKey` object would be stored at the URL  `https://<my-firebase-app>.firebaseio.com/someKey`.

So whenever you need to find data by **key**, just construct a path using a URL or `.child()`.

Comment: @DavidEast is this still true? I'm trying to do this with angularfire2

Answer (score 0):

I made something like this:

```
import firebase from 'firebase';
```

...

```
const item_key = "someKey"; // key of the single item in list

firebase.database().ref(`/list/${item_key}`)
  .on('value', snapshot => { // is called whenever value is changed
    console.log(snapshot.val());
    const item = snapshot.val(); // returned item === { foo: "bar", ... }
});
```

data structure:

```
{
  "list": {
    "someKey": {
      "foo": "bar",
      ...
    },
    ...
  }
}
```